# Knockout.js - xxxx is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to incorporate Knockout.js into a WebApplication.

The tutorial I am basing much of my code on is [here](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=webmail).

Basically - I have a list of items - I want to be able to click an item and have the corresponding data appear in a div at the bottom of the page. Eventually I'll use jquery.UI Dialog plugin to turn this div into a popup, but for now, I'm just trying to get the selectedItem to work.

My (simplified) code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/fZXAX/1/

> I just get the error:  *actionListViewModel.selectedActionId is not a function*.

I don't see the difference between this and the tutorial which uses selectedMailId in an identical way. The only difference between my code and the example is that I am not using literal notation.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
click: function() {actionListViewModel.selectedActionId(id)}
```

`actionListViewModel` is a constructor function, but you're acting as if it's an object.

See [this forked jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vsqDt/).  This line, which defines a constructor function

```
function actionListViewModel () {
```

was changed to be an instance of a new object, created by calling an anonymous constructor function.

```
var actionListViewModel = new function () {
```

and this line, where you were creating an instance of your previously defined function

```
ko.applyBindings(new actionListViewModel());
```

was changed to just pass in the instance that we setup earlier

```
ko.applyBindings(actionListViewModel);
```

Alternatively you could simply define a variable `viewModel` and set it `= new actionListViewModel();` and then update your click literal to point to `viewModel` instead of `actionListViewModel`.  You can see that approach [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8pG2P/)

Comment: How is it different from this example: http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=loadingsaving? (Which is what I based my code on - but now I'm trying to incorporate the click functionality).

Comment: never mind - I've fixed it: http://jsfiddle.net/fZXAX/2/ - I still don't understand your comment - I thought javascript objects and functions were pretty much synonymous, but I'm pretty new to OO javascript so it's a learning curve. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: That line isn't in the example, so it's completely different. I'm not quite sure what you're asking.

Comment: Well, JavaScript functions *are* objects, but the point is `selectedActionId` is a constructor function, which, when called with the `new` operator, returns an object with the `selectedActionId` method. `actionListViewModel` doesn't have that method. `new actionListViewModel()` does have that method.

Comment: Added some explanations and alternative solutions to the answer.  Btw BonyT, you might want to look through this http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/ it should help alot!  Specifically this section http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#30

Comment: ah - that makes sense the "loadingsaving" tutorial used the constructor function - and bound it to the page with the new taskListViewModel() call. The "singlepageapp" tutorial referenced in the original question, uses the click: function defined above. That example also sets the window.viewModel separately, but I think I am starting to understand the differences now. Thanks again.

Comment: @Allen Thanks for your edits - it's a much better answer! [I feel a bit bad for the upvotes now, so I've gone and upvoted some of your answers elsewhere :)]